# Type double byte character into vbscript file

Tags: unicode, encoding, vbscript, utf-8, ansi

I need to convert → (&rarr) to a symbol I can type into a ANSI VBScript file. I am writing a script that translates a select set of htmlcodes to their actual double byte symbols using a regex. Many languages accomplish this using "\0x8594;"... what is the equivelent in VBScript?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer was ChrW(8594)

Answer (score 1):

ChrW(&H8594)

Answer (score 1):

Note: Bob King's answer is correct for the information given. The problem is that alumb is mistaken about the meaning of a numeric character entity reference. → (&rarr; single right arrow) is, as stated, also identified as &#8594; but this is decimal and so is not equivalent to \x8594 in "many languages" (e.g. C++). This is why chrW(&H8594) gave the "wrong" character. Hexadecimal character entity references are specified using "&#x" instead of "&#". Thus &#x8594; (薔) = \x8594 = chrW(&H8594) while &#8594; (→) = chrW(8594) = \x2192.